# Optimized for loop python

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

Okay So, while solving a problem I was going through somebody else's code and they implemented a kind of for statement which I am not familiar with in Python. Sorry I am new to Python and google searches did not help me with this.

```
distance, food = min([(util.manhattanDistance(state, food), food) for food in foodList])
```

I kind of understand that this loops for the minimum value of food or distance or something, but am not sure.

Comment: They are passing a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to the [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) function.

Comment: Note that in this case, what they probably should have used is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) which would, barring some absurd cases involving pathological side-effects from the functions called, get the same result without pre-computing the whole list, getting the `min` and deleting it; instead, only one element would be generated at a time as `min` did its work, keeping memory usage to a minimum. Corrected code: `distance, food = min((util.manhattanDistance(state, food), food) for food in foodList)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the one line of list comprehension translates to for loop, and an assignment

```
    for food in foodList:
       food_list.append(util.manhattanDistance(state, food), food) <--> value of

    min_value = min(food_list)
```

Comment: yeah I tried it is right.. Just a minor change in your code to make it work.. but the logic is perfect.. thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` in this case is used to compute the elements of a new list by specifying an expression to evaluate *for* each element in an existing list.

As for how that is being used: the resulting list is passed to `min`, to compute the minimum of the elements of that list, which will be a pair of values: the distance and the food.  The minimum pair will be assigned to `distance,food`.

Comment: So is the new list distance or food. I am still a bit confused, I would be grateful if you can further explain it.